# Writing sentences to a textfile from a list of words - python

Tags: python

I have  a list of words that when combined form a sentence. I want to write this list into a text file, however, currently the list getting outputted vertically.

For example:

word_list = ["the", "winter", "is", "beautiful"]

At the moment the output is...

```
the
winter
is
beautiful
```

whereas I want it to be

```
the winter is beautiful.
```

My code:

```
def WriteToTextfile(list_to_write):
    new_writefile = open("text.txt","w")
    for k in list_to_write:
        new_writefile.write("%s\n" % k)
    new_writefile.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply join the words like this and then write

```
new_writefile.write(" ".join(list_to_write))
```

And always use `with`, when you are using files

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as new_writefile:
    new_writefile.write(" ".join(list_to_write))
```

Comment: Ok, but the textfile still contains only 1 line. I want it
to contain multiple lines where every line has 9-10 words in it. Because otherwise python is not reading it properly.

Comment: @user3083245 I think this has to be a separate question :)

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly adding the "\n" character, just remove it

```
def WriteToTextfile(list_to_write):
    new_writefile = open("text.txt","w")
    for k in list_to_write:
        new_writefile.write("%s " % k)
    new_writefile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the list before you write it to the file like so:

```
" ".join(list_to_write
```

and also use a with statement to write like this:

```
with open("text.txt","w") as new_writefile:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def WriteToTextfile(list_to_write):
    with open('text.txt', 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write('%s.' % (' '.join(list_to_write),))
```